# As If/As though - Which sentence should I use?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning, past-tense, vocabulary, present-tense

I comprehend *As Though/if* can take the present and past tense. The problem is that sometimes I don't know what are the nuances among those 3.
For instance:

> He looks as if *he knows it"
>
> He looks as if *he knew it*
>
> He looks as if *he'd known it*

Also, when changing the main clause to the past, should I use

> He looked as if *he'd known it*
>
> He looked as if *he knew it*

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could replace ***He looks as if*** by some syntactic equivalent, such as ***All the available evidence gave me the impression that***. Or simply remove it, since it makes no difference to the choice between *1: **He knows it,** 2: **He knew it,*** and *3: **He had known it***. Do you understand the difference between those last three alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the nuances, let's keep using the verb "to know", but change the rest of the example up a bit.

> John often talks about Bill Gates as if he **knows** him personally.

John may or may not know Bill Gates, so this is a hypothetical statement about the present, from a present point of reference.

> John often talks about my late grandfather as if he **knew** him personally.

My grandfather is no longer with us, so this is a hypothetical statement about the past, also from a present point of reference.

I'm not sure how to construct a hypothetical statement from a present point of reference using the past perfect tense. However, it's easy to modify the tense of the main clause in the above two examples:

> John often talked about Bill Gates as if he **knew** him personally.
>
> John often talked about my late grandfather as if he **had known** him personally.

The latter is a hypothetical statement from a past point of reference about something in the even further past (before the point of reference).